# Difference between printf and echo in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
$ printf 'apple' | wc -m
       5
$ echo 'apple' | wc -m
       6
```

Why printf prints 5 and echo prints 6 characters?

Comment: more details could be found here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: Try `echo -n 'apple' | wc -m`.

Comment: More details can be found in the manual page for [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins).

Comment: @ritesht93's answer is good: As a general rule it is helpful to actually *look* at output one is wondering about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First sentence of entry for `echo` in the `bash` man page (emphasis mine):

> Output  the  args,  separated  by  spaces, **followed by a newline**.

First sentence of the man page entry for `printf`:

> Write the formatted arguments to the standard output under the control of the format.

`printf` only prints what appears in the format; it does not append an implied newline.

There may be other difference between `echo "foo"` and `printf "foo"`, depending on what exactly `foo` is. The POSIX specification gives implementations broad discretion in how it implements `echo`, probably to avoid choosing from among the diverse historical implementations as the standard. Use `printf` when you rely on the precise output.

Comment: Although the `echo` man page is relevant in so far as the bash built-in certainly was carefully crafted to perfectly emulate the program's behavior, `/bin/echo`, which the man page documents,  is never executed in the OP's example.

Comment: I'm referring to the `echo` entry in the `bash` man page, but it certainly is ambiguous. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the difference ..

```
$printf 'abcd'
abcd$ echo 'abcd'
abcd
$
```

As you can see the additional char is newline `\n`

Comment: This is the perfect answer: Man page, shman page -- it may be out-of-date, inaccurate or, as in chepner's case, inapplicable. What counts is what happens.