# "echo" output different answer by sh and bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo, dash-shell

I ran my script using three ways and the output was different, could you explain to me why it works like that? Thanks!!
Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
#Program:
#     This program shows "Hello World!" in your screen.
echo -e "Hello World! \a\n" 
exit 0
```

And if i run it by bash and ./ like **bash sh01.sh** the output is

> Hello World!

However, if i use sh like **sh sh01.sh** it would be like

> -e Hello World!

And Here is some other information

1. OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3
2. type sh -> dash

Comment: Bash is a very extended shell, while Dash is a very basic and standard compliant shell. That means Bash can add extended versions of standard commands, like `echo` which according to the standard only takes *one* optional argument (and it isn't `-e`). See [this official POSIX reference about `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for more information.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603323/bash-different-between-printf-and-echo

Comment: I got it , Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is not very portable (even Bash's `echo` may behave differently on different OSes which may use different default options when compiling Bash). You can use `printf`. According to [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

> It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.
>   The `printf` utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the `echo` utility [...]

Comment: Yeah, a bunch of my scripts that used `echo -n` broke when OS X v10.5 shipped with `bash` compiled with different options. They switched it back in some later update, but I don't know exactly when because I'd switched all my scripts to use `printf` instead. `printf` is a bit more complicated to use than `echo`, but *way* more predictable.

Comment: Thank you! Later , i meet some similar situation again, like newgrp, behaves differently in ubuntu and OSX. TT . Now i have why hh