# Difference between echo and printf in Bash

Tags: bash, printf, echo, md5sum

I am reading lines of a file, converting each one to an md5 hash, and writing it to a second file. I have been getting different results based on using `printf` and `echo`.

```
printf $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt

echo $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt
```

For `printf` 00000 becomes `dcddb75469b4b4875094e14561e573d8`, but for echo 00000 becomes `81b4e43a7bcd862f3ac58b5f8568a668`.

I verified and the correct md5 hash sum for 00000 is `dcddb75469b4b4875094e14561e573d8` but I am confused on why?

Comment: echo puts a newline on the end of the string.  Use the `-n` option of echo to prevent that

Comment: so if I use `echo -n` it would be basically the same as `printf`? Is there a difference between using `echo -n` or `printf`?

Comment: Not for your specific case.   printf is way more flexibility and many more options - but you aren't using any of them.

Comment: Ahhh, okay thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `echo -n`. If you use `printf` and your file contains a line that contains a special sequence such as `%d`, you will get wrong results.

Comment: You should nearly always use `printf '%s' "$line"` instead of `printf $line`.   `printf '00000\n' | md5sum` will give you the same hash as that of `echo 00000 | md5sum`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between printf and echo in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603323/difference-between-printf-and-echo-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `echo $line` automatically includes a newline - which you can suppress with the `-n` option (sometimes - see below).  So this doesn't work:

```
echo $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt
```

But on bash this does:

```
echo -n $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt
```

But Not all versions of `echo` have an `-n` option.  The [echo documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) says:

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined.
> ... On XSI-conformant systems, if the first operand is -n, it shall be treated as a string, not an option.

Another alternative is using bash's `printf` command.  The [printf documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) says:

> The printf utility was added to provide functionality that has historically been provided by echo. However, due to irreconcilable differences in the various versions of echo extant, ...

So `printf` is the reliably portable way to go.  Here is a related answer with more details:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

But using `printf` is dangerous if you don't specify a format string, so even though this seems to work:

```
printf $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt
```

It will fail spectacularly when `$line` contains a percent sign or a backslash.  The first argument to `printf` is the format string and is treated specially. If the format string is invalid then `printf` produces an error to stderr and an empty string to stdout, which gives the wrong answer.  So instead you need:

```
printf "%s" "$line" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt
```

The `%s` tells `printf` to expect one more string parameter (which just happens to be `$line`) and you get the right output.

Fun fact: if you did want `printf` to add a trailing newline (you don't in this case) then you would

```
printf "%s\n" "$line" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> md5File.txt
```

Comment: What if your `line` contains whitespace?

Comment: I see you edited your answer after my comment.

Comment: @Roadowl  Sure - you were right.  I edited it quickly to try to fit in the 5-minute window (but I wasn't quite that fast) and then did a bit more testing for other corner cases before making a comment that I had applied your suggestion.

Comment: It's even worse than this; some versions of `echo` will just print `-n` as part of their output (and then go ahead and add a newline anyway). And they may do weird things with any backslashes in the string. `printf "%s" "$line"` is the way to go.

Comment: @GordonDavisson  Good catch.  I don't have my ksh-based RS6000 running AIX anymore, but if anything could do something unlike the way bash would do it, that would - According to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/e_commands/echo.html `echo -n` probably wouldn't have worked on that box. On the other hand, it might not have had printf either... I've added that warning to the answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Even bash's `echo` builtin will print the "-n", depending on certain run- and/or compile-time options. I know this because Mac OS X v10.5.0 shipped with bash compiled to do this by default, and it broke a bunch of my scripts. And that is when I joined the church of `printf`.

Comment: Which are all good reasons just to use `printf` and forget `echo`. Yes, you will be tempted to cheat because typing `echo "stuff"` is shorter than `printf "%s\n" "stuff"` -- don't give in. There is a bash 12-step program to help people free themselves from the `echo` addiction `:)`